# can normal hlml5 tags be used in ionic framework to give square buttons

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am trying to give square buttons in an app made using ionic framework. Its displaying blank. Any help? Here is my the http://codepen.io/sanand29/pen/mKkvw
`<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="dummy"></div>
            <div class="content">1</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="dummy"></div>
            <div class="content">1</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="dummy"></div>
            <div class="content">1</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="dummy"></div>
            <div class="content">1</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="dummy"></div>
            <div class="content">1</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="dummy"></div>
            <div class="content">1</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="dummy"></div>
            <div class="content">1</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="dummy"></div>
            <div class="content">1</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="dummy"></div>
            <div class="content">1</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
<table>`

when I am using this in ionic framework nothing is being displayed. How will I make responsive squares with a link to each boxes

Comment: What have you tried?  There is a reason that you have to insert code to post a link to codepen . . .

Comment: oops,, sorry I am new to this and I dont really understand how to use this stackoverflow.com. I tried giving code but its simply not taking. Forgive my foolishness and please help me

Comment: We can help you.  What EXACTLY is the problem, though?  I see nothing wrong with the codepen that you posted.

Comment: The problem is whenever I am giving codes of making square in that,, nothing is being displayed

Comment: To make things square, make the height and width the same